# PHP array finding element error

Tags: javascript, php

I've a javascript file that passes an argument to the backend php file. Which will try to find out which values are true.

This is the passed parameter,

```
{"2":true,"3":false,"4":true}
```

This is the php code that will extract the keys of the True arrays,

```
<?php
  print_r(loop_filters($_REQUEST['filters']));

// Functions starts here

  function loop_filters($filters)
  {
    $filters = json_decode($filters);
    // return $filters;
    $filter_array = [];

    while($filter_key = current($filters))
    {
      if($filter_key === true)
      {
        $filter_array[] = key($filters);
      }
      next($filters);
    }
    return $filter_array;
  }
?>
```

However the output is

```
Array ( [0] => 2 )
```

Why is it not detecting 4 as true and give an output like

```
Array ( [0] => 2 , [1] => 4)
```

What's wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Seriously?  Write a function to foreach over the whole thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't work simply because of this:

```
while($filter_key = current($filters))
```

Because in the second iteration your value will be: `FALSE` and as we all know:

```
while(FALSE)
```

This won't run, so you end the loop after the first iteration already.

How to solve it? Just simply remove the `next()` calls and replace the while loop with a foreach loop, e.g.

```
function loop_filters($filters) {
    $filters = json_decode($filters);

    foreach($filters as $key => $filter_key) {
        if($filter_key === true) {
            $filter_array[] = $key;
        }
    }

    return $filter_array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rizier123 solves the issue with your code, however for this specific case, to get the keys of the `true` values it's much simpler:

```
$filter_array = array_keys($filters, true, true);
```

Comment: With this you only filter "false" values out. So 1, 34, ... would also pass this. (=> `array_filter($filters, function($v){return $v === TRUE;})`)

Comment: Actually, it was much easier :-)

Comment: Yep, I don't think it goes simpler than that :)